# epson sdk for javascript in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, import, iife, epson, pos

Am trying to print a receipt using the ePos sdk from epson using the tm-U220 and tm-220ii.

Note:
the npm escpos package works fine but is not an option because the package cant use the double comand that DOUBLES the size of the font in the tm-U220.

The epson sdk works fine if I create a single HTML page with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tercer intento</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      
    </div>
    <script src="epos-2.17.0.js"></script>
    <script>
var printer = null;
var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
ePosDev.connect('192.168.6.142', 8008, cbConnect);
function cbConnect(data) {
    if(data == 'OK' || data == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK') {
        ePosDev.createDevice('matricial', ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,
                              {'crypto':false, 'buffer':false}, cbCreateDevice_printer);
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
}
function cbCreateDevice_printer(devobj, retcode) {
    if( retcode == 'OK' ) {
        printer = devobj;
        printer.timeout = 60000;
        printer.onreceive = function (res) { alert(res.success); };
        printer.oncoveropen = function () { alert('coveropen'); };
        print();
    } else {
        alert(retcode);
    }
}

function print() {
    printer.addTextLang('en');
    printer.addTextDouble(true, true);
    printer.addText('Total\n 3656L.\n');
    printer.addCut(printer.CUT_FEED);
    printer.send();
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want this logic into a vue component. but I can't import or require the "epos-2.17.0.js" file
example:

```
(file structure)
-node_modules
-public
-src
--components (where the component is)
--js (where the sdk is)
```

//-------inside vue component------------

```
<script>
import epson from '../../public/epos-2.17.0';
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  setup(){
    const imprimir = () =>{
      var printer = null;
       var ePosDev = new epson.ePOSDevice();
      ePosDev.connect('192.168.6.142', 9100, cbConnect);
      function cbConnect(data) {
          if(data == 'OK' || data == 'SSL_CONNECT_OK') {
              ePosDev.createDevice('matricial', ePosDev.DEVICE_TYPE_PRINTER,
                                    {'crypto':false, 'buffer':false}, cbCreateDevice_printer);
          } else {
              alert(data);
          }
      }
      function cbCreateDevice_printer(devobj, retcode) {
          if( retcode == 'OK' ) {
              printer = devobj;
              printer.timeout = 60000;
              printer.onreceive = function (res) { alert(res.success); };
              printer.oncoveropen = function () { alert('coveropen'); };
              print();
          } else {
              alert(retcode);
          }
      }

      function print() {
          printer.addTextLang('en');
          printer.addTextDouble(true, true);
          printer.addText('Total\n 3656L.\n');
          printer.addCut(printer.CUT_FEED);
          printer.send();
      }
      // return 1;
    }//imprimir
  return{imprimir}
  }//setup

}//export
</script>
```

Is the exact same as in the single HTML page but now the browser console show error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _public_epos_2_17_0__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.ePOSDevice is not a constructor
    at Proxy.imprimir (HelloWorld.vue?fdab:12)
    at Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> (HelloWorld.vue?fdab:2)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163)
    at HTMLButtonElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:367)
imprimir @ HelloWorld.vue?fdab:12
Object.onClick._cache.<computed>._cache.<computed> @ HelloWorld.vue?fdab:2
callWithErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:154
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:163
invoker @ runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js?830f:367
```

Edit#1
I found out that the epson library is called a IIFE, and that could explain the problem. However, I can't find info on how to use a IIFE in a vue component.